# Proxy that can use a pac file as parent proxy

Tags: proxy

I want to setup a caching proxy that will use a pac (proxy autoconfiguration) file as parent proxy (lookup in a pac proxy file to choose which parent proxy to use).
I want to know if anyone knows a proxy server that supports this.

The goal is to be able to use applications that doesn't support pac files with the pac file I normally use.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer, but a solution that will work.

Write a simple proxy (or modify [an existing one](http://proxies.xhaus.com/)) that will listen on a specific port at localhost and redirect all requests to whatever proxy it finds using proxy.pac file.

Then take your favourite caching proxy, e.g. squid, and configure it to use your proxy.

**Parsing PAC files**

- Python: [pacparser](http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/) library;
- C#: [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/using_pac_files_proxy.aspx), [answer at msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b619c750-852a-4567-aa68-f7b03c6a4717)

Comment: Is there anyone willing to do this for me? I'll give the bounty for this. (so put it in an answer not a comment)