# Proxy that can use a PAC (Proxy Auto-Configuration) file as parent proxy; resisting in 2022

Tags: proxy

I would like to ask the same question as this one: [Proxy that can use a pac file as parent proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/339966/proxy-that-can-use-a-pac-file-as-parent-proxy). It's 11 years later now, and there is no accepted answer on that question, so I'm hoping there are better answers.

Here is the content of that other question:

> I want to setup a caching proxy that will use a pac (proxy autoconfiguration) file as parent proxy (lookup in a pac proxy file to choose which parent proxy to use). I want to know if anyone knows a proxy server that supports this.
>
> The goal is to be able to use applications that doesn't support pac files with the pac file I normally use.

Related questions:

- [Linux support for proxy PAC files](https://serverfault.com/questions/167361/linux-support-for-proxy-pac-files)
- [Is there any tool for setting up proxy with pac file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272076/is-there-any-tool-for-setting-up-proxy-with-pac-file)

In my attempts to finding a solution I have found the following:

There are packages to work with PAC files

- Run PAC files: https://github.com/manugarg/pacparser
- Find and use PAC files: https://github.com/carsonyl/pypac
- Run PAC files and embed into applications: https://github.com/libproxy/libproxy

There have been discussions/attempts to integrate this into proxy servers:

- TinyProxy fork: https://github.com/andyetitmoves/tinyproxy/tree/libproxy-upstream
- TinyProxy abandoned PR: https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/pull/228
- Polipo discussion: https://www.mail-archive.com/polipo-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01394.html

Does anyone have a working solution? Thank you